# Import Excel file with different attributes from a different class in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to import excel with different attributes from different class. I have two models Student and Guardian.The problem is when I import File as Student it must get inserted in Student table and when I Import Guardian File it should get inserted in Guardian table. But for now I am not getting how the controller will get that the file selected is file of Student or Guardian. Now when when i write `Guardian.import(params[:file])` the file gets inserted in guardian table and when I do `Student.import(params[:file])` the file gets inserted in Student table.

**controller**

```
def import
    Guardian.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to import_reports_path, notice: "Students imported."
end
```

**model**

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    row = clean_for row, COLUMNS_TO_STRING
    record = Student.find_by(:batch_id =>        row["batch_id"],:class_roll_no => row["class_roll_no"],:phone1 =>   row["phone1"],:phone2 => row["phone2"]) || new
    guardian = Guardian.find_by(:student_id => row["student_id"]) || new
    record.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
    guardian.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
    record.save!
    guardian.save!
  end
 end

def self.clean_for row_as_hash, string_columns_array
  row_as_hash.each do |key, value|
    if string_columns_array.include?key
      row_as_hash[key] = value.to_i.to_s
    end
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
end
end
```

**view**

```
<h1>IMPORT</h1>
<div class = "well">
<p>

<%= form_tag import_reports_path do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file%>
   <br>
  <%= submit_tag "Import",class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have different logins for student and guardian ?? and the view you specified for importing file is common for both ?

Comment: @Dhanshree You can pass the hidden field. if you have different login of student and Guardian

Comment: @chirag-arya The importing file is common to both.

Comment: @Dhanshree did you specified role for user like. guardian or student ?

Comment: @Vishal yes I have roles as Guardian, Student.

Comment: @Dhanshree can you get the current user's role ? If Yes than you can easily pass the id of student or guardian in hidden field tag. and insert data in tables

Comment: @Vishal I have roles as Admin, SuperAdmin, Student, Employee, Guardian. When i logged in as SuperAdmin or Admin I can import Student and Guardian. For now I am getting error when I import.  `undefined method `original_filename' for "import.xlsx":String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to import excel with different attributes from different class.
Here i found a good way to solve this problem.
As I wanted to maintain a report of student and guardian excel data.
My mistake was I didn't check the report name i.e **Student,Guardian** There was a mistake in controller

> Here is solution to my question:

**report_controller.rb**

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
before_action :load_report, only: [:import, :import_form], unless: -> { params[:id].nil? }
def import_form
end

def import
 importer = @report.name == 'Guardian' ? Guardian : Student
 importer.import(params[:file])
 redirect_to import_form_report_path, notice: "#{importer}s imported."
end

private 

def load_report
 @report = Report.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
end
```

> Change Routes

**routes.rb**

```
 member do 
      get :import_form
      post :import 
    end
```

**view**

```
<%= form_tag import_report_path(@report), method: :post, multipart: true do %>
```

**link**

```
<td><%= link_to 'IMPORT' , import_form_report_path(report)%></td>
```

> The code in student.rb and guardian.rb will remain same as above.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally 2 ways for this depending on how your current structure is. If you have different logins tied to each type, then you can simply do it in the controller by checking something like `current_user.role`?

```
def importer
  if current_user.guardian?
    Guardian
  else
    Student
  end
end
```

If you had different pages with different forms, you could always add in a hidden field in the form that sends in a `role`

```
def importer
  params[:role] == :guardian ? Guardian : Student
end
```

Either of the above can be added into the controller. Finally, you just need to use that method.

```
importer.import(params[:file])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but only the **if** condition is getting executed.  i.e the Student excel is not getting imported only guardian file is imported by trying this code. What should I do? @ho-man

Comment: You need to provide more information on how you tell a Guardian from a Student